# Azure Custom Speech Model: Use existing model as a base model

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I created model base on my datasets. Can I use this model as a base model for creation of another model, if I want to append more datasets to existing ones?

when I try to do so, I get http 400, and message: "The base model isn't valid for this operation"

Comment: Did you create a custom language model using the azure ui?

Comment: I used rest apis

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make your custom model the base model. The custom model is something which was created over the base model. All you need is to find the endpointId of the custom model and then execute your request against that model either using the sdk or using the rest api.

The below is how a sample custom endpoint response looks like.
The id which ends in the "f203" is the custom model endpointId and the id which ends in "ddcd" is the base model endpointId.

```
{
      "self": "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.0/models/****1e6c-****-****-****-c25f****f203",
      "baseModel": {
        "self": "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.0/models/base/****f802-****-****-****-8f1b****ddcd"
      },
      "datasets": [],
      "links": {
        "manifest": "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.0/models/****1e6c-****-****-****-c25f****f203/manifest",
        "copyTo": "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.0/models/****1e6c-****-****-****-c25f****f203/copyto"
      },
      "properties": {
        "deprecationDates": {
          "adaptationDateTime": "2021-10-15T00:00:00Z",
          "transcriptionDateTime": "2022-10-15T00:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      "lastActionDateTime": "2020-08-27T07:20:50Z",
      "status": "Succeeded",
      "createdDateTime": "2020-08-27T07:18:36Z",
      "locale": "en-NZ",
      "displayName": "Iteration 1",
      "description": "Baseline Model with Random Splitting of Dataset",
      "customProperties": {
        "PortalAPIVersion": "3"
      }
    }
```

Please have a look at the below link and play around with the apis.

[Speech to Text API v3.0 REST Console](https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/GetModels)

Comment: I've already used those apis to create dataset, model and endpoint.

In my case I have already trained model which contains 2 hours of audio. Now I want to add 10 mins of another dataset to this model. Is there a way to not to retrain entire model which is now 2h10mins in total, but only train 10min of audio, and add it to existing model?

Comment: I am not sure if that is available in Custom Model training in Azure. As fas as I know, you will need to create a new dataset with 2 hour 10 mins audio samples and retrain the base model again. At least thats how we have done it.